# jQuery Mobile change data-split-icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to change to data-split-icon.

jQuery Mobile Api says:
The icon for the split button can be set at the list level by adding the data-split-icon.

Therefore I tried:

```
    <li data-split-icon="minus">
```

You can try that here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/UV7Xn/)

Unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a different icon for a specific split button, add `data-icon` to split button in HTML markup.

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
  </a>
  <!-- split button -->
  <a data-icon="minus"></a>
</li>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UV7Xn/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

In your jsfiddle there is a `jqueryUI` dependece. If you remove that, then it will work as expected. Apparentrly there is a conflict. In general I think `jqueryUI` and `jqueryMobile` don't work well together.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLj4A/)

Comment: In my case it was a conflict with underscore. I had to add the <%=target.id=> definition to the end of the button tag <a .... id=<%= ..%>> before I had that in the beginning <a id=<...> ... > That didn't work then.

Comment: underscore.js? You didn't include that in your fiddle.